# How to add border to grid Window Phone (C#)

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, grid, border, windows-phone-8.1

I create a grid and add border on that grid, but I it's made error when I run
My code is :

```
Border border = new Border();
border.BorderBrush = new SolidColorBrush(StrongBlackColor);
border.BorderThickness = new Thickness(1, 1, 1, 1);
Grid.SetColumn(border, 0);
Grid.SetRow(border, 0);

m_Board[i, j].Children.Add(border);
// m_Board is a type Grid[,]
```

Comment: What's the error? It's difficult to say what's going wrong without that detail.

Answer (score 0):

```
    Border b = new Border();
    Grid.SetColumn(b, 0);
    Grid.SetColumnSpan(b, 4);
    Grid.SetRowSpan(b, 4);
    b.CornerRadius = new CornerRadius(1);
    b.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
    // Then add your border to the grid
    m_Board.Children.Add(b);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Border border  = new Border();
border.BorderBrush = new SolidColorBrush(StrongBlackColor);
border.BorderThickness = new Thickness(1, 1, 1, 1);
Grid.SetColumn(border, 0);
Grid.SetRow(border, 0);
border.Child(yourgrid),
```